# Insert items from one collection to another by condition and iterate over both collections using Google Guava or java 8 Stream API

Tags: java, collections, java-8, java-stream, guava

I have a specific case for two collections of such items:

```
public class Item {
    private Long id;
    private boolean isVisible;
}
```

List A contains items both visible and invisible.

List B contains only visible items from list A, but ordered (indexed) differently.

I need a result list with visible items layed down in relative order of B, and with unchanged relative order of invisible items from A. So far, the only way I could do it right is through iterators:

```
Iterator<Item> ai = A.listIterator();
Iterator<Item> bi = B.iterator();
while(ai.hasNext() && bi.hasNext()) {
    Item next = ai.next();
    if (next.isVisible() && B.contains(next)) {
        ai.set(bi.next())
    }
}
```

So we're replacing every next visible item in A contained in B, with item from B. I wonder if there is more beautiful solution to this problem through either Guava or Stream API.

Comment: Seems pretty clean to me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need to share the same object between listA and listB, then you can do the following

loop through listA,
 - if a is invisible, return a,
 - if a is visible, return b.
then combine back into a list and replace the list (or create a new list if needed).

```
    AtomicInteger index = new AtomicInteger();
    listA = listA.stream()
            .map(a -> a.isVisible ? listB.get(index.getAndIncrement()) :  a)
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: Exaclty what I've been looking for. Thanks!

Comment: `map()` functions shouldn't be stateful. This will fail in parallel.

Answer (score 2):

Implement a comparator that checks if both items are visible, and thus both are in the B list. Use their position in the B list to determine the sort order. If one of them is not visible the order should be on the A list.

```
class CustomSort implements Comparator<Item> {
    public int compare(Item i1, Item i2) {
        if (i1.isVisible() && i2.isVisible()) {
           return bi.indexOf(i1) - bi.indexOf(i2);
        }

        return ai.indexOf(i1) - ai.indexOf(i2);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

assume Capital = VISIBLE, small caps = INVISIBLE

> AList = { A, a, B, C, b, c, D, d, e }; //both Visible & Invisible.
>   BList = { C, D, B, A } ; //only Visible with different order.

from your requirement

> "So we're replacing every next visible item in A contained in B, with item from B. I wonder if there is more beautiful solution to this problem through either Guava or Stream API."

you want the result to be ->

> CList = { C, a, D, B, b, c, A, d, e}; // resort the Visible items to B's order

you can first filter Stream of A to show only visible items,
then replace that item ID with the value of B at that relative position.
the key is to use AtomicInteger

```
        AtomicInteger index = new AtomicInteger();
        itemA.stream().filter(a -> a.isVisible)
                .forEach(a -> {
                    a.id = itemB.get(index.getAndIncrement()).id;
                });
```

The following is the full codes: -

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicInteger;
import java.util.stream.IntStream;

public class StreamExample {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<Item> itemA = new ArrayList<>();
        List<Item> itemB = new ArrayList<>();

        itemA.add(new Item("A"));
        itemA.add(new Item("a", false));
        itemA.add(new Item("B"));
        itemA.add(new Item("C"));
        itemA.add(new Item("b", false));
        itemA.add(new Item("c", false));
        itemA.add(new Item("D"));
        itemA.add(new Item("e", false));

        itemB.add(new Item("C"));
        itemB.add(new Item("D"));
        itemB.add(new Item("B"));
        itemB.add(new Item("A"));

        System.out.println("BEFORE: ");
        System.out.println("A: ");
        itemA.forEach(System.out::print);
        System.out.println("\nB: ");
        itemB.forEach(System.out::print);

        AtomicInteger index = new AtomicInteger();
        itemA.stream().filter(a -> a.isVisible)
                .forEach(a -> {
                    a.id = itemB.get(index.getAndIncrement()).id;
                });

        System.out.println("\nAFTER: ");
        System.out.println("A: ");
        itemA.forEach(System.out::print);


    }
}


class Item {
    String id;
    boolean isVisible = true;

    public Item(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public Item(String id, boolean isVisible) {
        this.id = id;
        this.isVisible = isVisible;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return " {'" + id + '\'' +
                '}';
    }
}
```

The following is the output

```
BEFORE: 
A: 
 {'A'} {'a'} {'B'} {'C'} {'b'} {'c'} {'D'} {'e'}
B: 
 {'C'} {'D'} {'B'} {'A'}
AFTER: 
A: 
 {'C'} {'a'} {'D'} {'B'} {'b'} {'c'} {'A'} {'e'}
```

Comment: That is not exactly what I'm looking for, though. I need to replace the Item itself, not reset it's id. I suppose, Angel Koh's example below does what I need.
Thank you for the answer anyway!